# How to process dynamically added via javascript controls on server-side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to make a form that consists of 3 parts:

1. **"Add number" section** 
   Here i enter some numbers from keyboard
   they should have some certain format and exclude duplicating. Validation of format and duplicates is to be done via jquery validation plugin.
2. **"Numbers" section**
   this section is dynamically filled via js. if numbers from "add number" section are valid, and user clicks on Add button, we add a row with a number to a table element (label and "delete" button). it has max size - 50 numbers (or rows, as it'a `<table>`)
3. **submit button**
   on submit we make postback
   the thing i don't understand - ***how to process dynamically added labels with numbers on server side***
   here is a draft i made for the form:
   [image: form]

here is aspx layout:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="AddPanel">
                <tr>
                    <th>AddNumber</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>..... .....</table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClientClick="AddNumber();return false;">Add</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="numberList">
                <tr>
                    <th>Numbers</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:ImageButton ID="Submit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

here is js code:

```
function AddNumber() {
    $("#AddPanel input[type=text]")
        .filter(function () {
        return this.value.length !== 0;
    })
        .each(function () {

        // find table and insert row
        var table = document.getElementById('numberList');
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var lbl = document.createElement("label");
        lbl.innerHTML = this.value;
        cell1.appendChild(lbl);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var removeBtn = document.createElement("img");
        removeBtn.src = "imgs/Buttons/delete.png";
        removeBtn.title = "Remove";
        removeBtn.name = "Remove";
        removeBtn.onclick = function () {
            Remove(this);
            return false;
        };
        cell2.appendChild(removeBtn);
    });
    // clear all inputs
    $('#AddPanel').find('input:text').val('');
}

function Remove(src) {
    var oRow = src.parentElement.parentElement;

    //once the row reference is obtained, delete it passing in its rowIndex   
    document.all("numberList").deleteRow(oRow.rowIndex);
}
```

i know the code is ugly. your comments on how to improve it will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot process labels on the server side. It is common to add hidden inputs at the same time as the labels, so that the data will be sent to the server side code.

Here is a sample hidden input that you would need to create:

```
<input type="hidden" name="number-field" value="234" />
```

Here is a JS Fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/vmH7P/1/

On the server side, you do not need to uniquely name your inputs. ASP.NET will turn it into an array. Which you can access with this code:

```
if(this.Request.Form["number-field"] != null)
{
    foreach(var numberString in this.Request.Form["number-field"])
    {
        int numberValue;
        if(int.TryParse(numberString, out numberValue))
        {
            processNumber(numberValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot fetch the data available inside label. what you can do is add a hidden field along with the label on each row. this hidden field will also contain the same value as the label. then on server side parse the values from hidden field.

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var lbl = document.createElement("label");
var hf = document.createElement('input');
hf.setAttribute('type','hidden');
hf.setAttribute('name', 'hf'+rowCount);//this will create unique name for each hiddenfield
hf.setAttribute('value',this.value);
lbl .innerHTML = this.value;
cell1.appendChild(lbl );
cell1.appendChild(hf);
```

now on the server side you will process the value from the hidden fields. something like this

```
for(int i=0;;i++)//considering your first row starts from 0
{
    if(Request["hf"+i] == null) break;
    string value = Request["hf"+i].ToString(); //process the value
}
```